# What is the file signature for .F4V?

Tags: flash, adobe, file-type

What is the hex signature for a .f4v file?

It is not listed in [File Signatures Table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) nor could I find it in Adobe specs. Or am I misunderstanding something here? The purpose is to verify an uploaded file. Thanks.

Comment: this might help - http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the mentioned specs, an F4V file is composed of boxes. There are a couple of dozens types of boxes. A box has a header that states its type and there is a different signature for each box type - these are described in the specs. Furthermore, the order in which the boxes go is not strictly specified. The specs state that

> the "ftyp" box should be placed as
>   early as possible

This type of box is required in a F4V file, but I wonder if one can trust it to always be the first one.

So I guess that there is no single signature code for the F4V file, but rather a couple dozens that might indicate an f4v, with ones occurring more often than others.

My conclusions are based on the adobe specifications http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf

Thanks to www0z0k for pointing it out.